# How should I copy part of content in form after clicking the button in Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue js right now and I am trying to duplicate some codes in template. As I do not know how many form it needs so it must be flexible.

My template code

```
<form @submit="duplicated">
  <b-form-input id="name" v-model="name" type="text" required/>
  ... other codes needs to copy

  <b-button type="submit">Save</b-button> 
  <!-- after clicking the button, the website should show two forms -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store a variable in data and use v-for in your form.

```
<form v-for="(form,index) in numberofForms" :key="index"
   @submit.prevent = "numberofForms++" >
  <b-form-input id="name" v-model="name" type="text" required/>
  ... other codes needs to copy

  <b-button type="submit">Save</b-button> 
</form>

export default {
...
data() {
 return {
  numberofForms: 1,
  }
 },
};
```